# Sort multidimensional associative array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to sort the following array by score

```
$questionsets = array(
    "A" => array("category" => "Some Category A", "score" => 0),
    "B" => array("category" => "Some Category B", "score" => 29),
    "C" => array("category" => "Some Category C", "score" => 12),
    "D" => array("category" => "Some Category D", "score" => 88),
    "E" => array("category" => "Some Category E", "score" => 4),
    "F" => array("category" => "Some Category F", "score" => 22),
    "G" => array("category" => "Some Category G", "score" => 20),
    "H" => array("category" => "Some Category H", "score" => 40),
    "I" => array("category" => "Some Category I", "score" => 42)
);

$questionsets = array_msort($questionsets, array('score'=>SORT_DESC));
```

This doesn't work and I'm not finding any documentation or examples that help. I've tried using `array_multisort()` and `usort()` but with no success.

What is the clean way to sort this array by `score` in descending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use multi-sort if you're only interested in one dimension. Do this instead to sort in descending order of score:

```
usort($questionsets,function($a,$b){return $b['score']-$a['score'];});
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/dsep9)

Comment: This works perfect and it makes sense to me too. Thank you.

Comment: I just discovered that the first dimensions "A", "B", etc. are now showing up as numeric - [0], [1], etc. Is there a way of retaining the letters? These are the main keys.

Comment: For anyone else having the problem of retaining the array index key, use `uasort` instead.